# NetSuite OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials using Postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, netsuite, suitescript2.0, appian

I am trying to connect netsuite using Postman's get auth code functionality. According to NetSuite help center a POST request needs to be sent to the token endpoint with the JW token and grant type.

But if we go to postman and select Oauth 2.0 client credentials in the Authorization then we get a button "get auth code" And fields like client id, client secret and the urls. After entering all the details its not working.

Only the POST request is working.

The reason I am asking this is I am trying call some restlets from Appian. But in the Appian screen we only get client id, client secret, auth url and token url field.

Any idea on this

I am trying to connect netsuite using Postman's get auth code functionality. According to NetSuite help center a POST request needs to be sent to the token endpoint with the JW token and grant type.

But if we go to postman and select Oauth 2.0 client credentials in the Authorization then we get a button "get auth code" And fields like client id, client secret and the urls. After entering all the details its not working.

Only the POST request is working.

The reason I am asking this is I am trying call some restlets from Appian. But in the Appian screen we only get client id, client secret, auth url and token url field.

Any idea on this

Comment: i know your pain, i worked on NetSuite before and because Oracle is so closed source, there is hardly any searchable public info out there. All support and forums are within Oracle/NetSuite's system. I'd suggest raising a ticket with NetSuite support or searching the resources inside the NetSuite web console.